# Process volume and trackbar

Tags: c#, audio

I have a trackbar in my form that has a range of 1-100 (for volume). I am looking for a way to set the audio output volume to a value I've entered (e.g. trackbar's value) but ONLY for my application.

Didn't find something in the web.

Regards

Comment: your using Wpf right?

Comment: Unfortunately, WinForms...

Comment: no problem man here's an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        // Calculate the volume that's being set
        double newVolume = ushort.MaxValue * trackBar1.Value/ 10.0;

        uint v = ((uint) newVolume) & 0xffff;
        uint vAll = v | (v << 16);

        // Set the volume
        int retVal = NativeMethods.WaveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, vAll);



        bool playRetVal = NativeMethods.PlaySound("tada.wav", IntPtr.Zero, 0x2001);


    }
}

static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "waveOutSetVolume")]
    public static extern int WaveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hwo, uint dwVolume);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool PlaySound(string pszSound, IntPtr hmod, uint fdwSound);
}
```

This should  simply work. i hope i didnt miss anything.

Comment: So this is for my application only? And what if I don't play just a sound and a sound is coming from a control (e.g. internetexplorer)? Regards

Comment: @Jan the sound play is just a test i used to see if it actually owrks. just remove the last line  `bool playRetVal = NativeMethods.PlaySound("tada.wav", IntPtr.Zero, 0x2001);` here.  I would appreciate if you could mark my answer :)

Comment: @Jan no problem. any other questions?

Comment: Yeh, is there a way to record that stuff then?

Comment: @Jan what do you mean by saying `that stuff`?

Comment: The output of my application